# USB to Ethernet controller, RTL8153, without EEPROM and only 3.3 V

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, ethernet, eeprom

I want to implement an RTL8153 controller in the simplest and most compact way possible on the PCB of an Arduino project. It's a driver-free (CDC-ECM) USB to Ethernet PHY controller.

Can it be used out of the box without an EEPROM attached or external configuration?

Even after reading the datasheet ten times, I don't understand what the EEPROM's role is, but I found a product that doesn't use it (see the attached picture), so maybe it's not mandatory.

Also, the rest of my project uses 3.3 V, and I'm thinking of bypassing the internal 5 V to 3.3 V converter of the chip and only powering it with 3.3 V, as the converter is only inside the controller for convenience, but the chip really runs with 3.3 V, right?

[image: waveshare simple rtl8153 ust to ethernet]

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Doing an USB/Ethernet controller on a deeply embedded platform including your owns hard and software design: the supply voltage are the least of your problems :) this projects is a bit bigger than I think you might be currently appreciating. The eeprom stores configuration and hardware address data.

Comment: There’s a number of Arduini boards with native ethernet that are most likely simpler and cheaper than your solution. Unless there’s drivers specifically written for Arduino for that chip, then you’re in for a rough ride.

Comment: Please be aware that your Arduino needs to take the role of a USB host. Most Arduinos cannot do this.